Drupal - Advanced Search
My current environment is:

Drupal 10.2.5
PHP: 8.2.15
MySQL: 8.0.36
List search related modules installed:

search_api_solr >> Version: 4.3.3
search_api >> Version: 8.x-1.34
facets >> Version: 2.0.7
advanced_search >> Version: 2.0.1



My goal is to have and advanced search like the one below: with a search box and filters

.
Where under the 'Title', it will contain a drop down list with all the different indexed fields that I would like to filter by, such as:

.
Where under 'Contains', it will be listing the different options such as:

.
and to the right the option of adding new rows with more filters, such as ("+" sign):

.
I've looked into the 'advanced search' module, and it looks like it offers something very similar to what I'm looking for.
I've read the 'advanced_search' documentation.
But I'm having a hard time implementing it.
The instruction under Configure Collection Search

To support collection based searches you need to index the
field_member_of for every repository item as well define a new field
that captures the full hierarchy of field_member_of for each
repository item.

Where do I set field_member_of?
Many thanks in advance for your help!

A member from the Islandora community guided me.
Here is what I needed to do.
In the desired 'content type', I had to create a field -for convenience and consistency, name it "Member of" > machine name: "field_member_of".
Here comes the key part, set it up as a Entity reference > Reference type: Content
Content type: Repository Item

In my case the name of my 'content type' was 'Metadata Record'

Then in the Solr index page proceed to index the field; indexed it twice:

the entire field
drill down to get the title

I still have things to figure out to make it work; however, this would be the response to this question.

You first need to enable the Search API and Search API Solr modules.

Once enabled, you can go to: <YOUR DRUPAL'S DOMAIN>/admin/config/search/search-api
Here you must create an indexing server using solr.

Once your server has been created, create an index. This index will belong to your server and in it you must select the content types you want to index and HERE IS WHRE YOU CAN SELECT the fields of those same content types.
Once everything is set up, just run the indexing job and you're done!


not sure if this answer addresses the question. Seems the OP is asking how to set up the filters, not how to set up solr

This is not solr setup. It’s where he will can index all the content managing the field of the same.

@PipoBizelli thanks for your suggestion; I actually did have already all those steps completed.

@2pha thanks for your response; my question was related to setting up the 'Advanced Search' which the instructions related to the 'field_member_of' field; which I did not know where to find it.
